# How to read a large file of Strings in chunks, each time from different offset, in Java?

Tags: java, file, memory, bufferedreader

I have a large file that consists of several lines, where each line is actually one word of English. The complete file does not fit in memory. As such, I want to process it chunk by chunk. So, I need to implement something like this:

1. Method1 : Read one chunk, call Method 2.
2. Method2: Do some processing on the strings in that chunk and go back Step 1.

I have two questions.

**1.** How can one implement Method1? I know very well how to implement Method2.

I know how to use BufferedReader to read a large file line-by-line. e.g.,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       // process the line.
    }
```

But I would like to read more lines instead of one line, and process all of them in Method2. Then, when I am back to Method1, I want to load several lines once again...

**2.** My assumption is that it is more efficient (performance wise), to process a chunk of lines rather than process each line. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: You need to make a good-faith effort at writing some code, first, then you can ask about specific issues you run into along the way here. We're not just going to write code for you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for the comment. I have tried to make the question clearer. I expect no one to write any code for me. I can't figure out the right API, and am only hoping that somebody will point me toward it.

Comment: Have you considered Hadoop map/reduce ? http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Thanks. Never used that before, let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BufferedReader effectively takes care of *reading* the lines in chunks.

So really your choice is between:

- after each call to readLine(), call your method to process it
- after each call to readLine(), add the line to a list, and then every time the list gets to some size, call your method to process the list, then clear it down

So the main factor is what your "processing" actually does: does it logically make sense to run the process on several lines at once, and is there some optimisation that the processing method can include if several lines are passed to it at once?

Answer (score 0):

It's just basic programming, if you want to read more than 1 line, do so.

```
void method1(java.io.File file) throws IOException {
        int n = 10; // Number of lines to read
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<String> lines;
        do {
            lines = readNLines(br, n);
            method2(lines);
        } while (!lines.isEmpty());
    }

    public void method2(List<String> lines) {
        // processing...
    }

    private List<String> readNLines(BufferedReader reader, int numberOfLines) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(numberOfLines);
        String line;
        while (lines.size() < numberOfLines && ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        return lines;
    }
```